# Why are non-perturbative solutions important and how to take them into account?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, symmetry-breaking, instantons, solitons

I am guilty of studying physics with an almost complete focus on the mathematical constructions (together with the motivating physical premisses) and ignoring the semantic physical intuition, which I'm currently trying to fix because it hinders my research.

One thing that I struggle to accept are arguments stating or implying that, for instance, in a spontaneously broken theory, we "expand the field around the vacuum to study the excitations around it". My educated impression was always that the reason why we favour a point within the vacuum manifold and "redefine the field around it" (call the new field an "excitation", if you will, but this is just an added confusion to me) is simply that the 'normalization'

$$
\left<\text{vac}\right|\phi\left|\text{vac}\right> =0
$$
is required for the LSZ formula to work in the conventional form.

The argument above seems to imply (and explicitly states within a few lecture notes that can be found online) that at some point within perturbative QFT an expansion *on the fields* is effected, which makes no sense to me. I know of no physical principle which require fields configurations to be small in a generalized sense in a way to allow us to expand local operators in powers of it -- instead, perturbative QFT is based upon an expansion on small coupling constants, in regimes where this is valid (not to mention expansions on alternative small power counting parameters on EFT).

A related specific matter regarding which I cannot convince myself of what is commonly stated, is the one of non-perturbative solutions, such as domain walls. The title of my question is sensationalist, since it is obvious that an existing static, finite energy (or finite energy density) exact solution to the field equations is physically important. Now let me contextualize and state my doubt:

A domain wall is an exact solution which interpolates between two vacua related by a discrete symmetry: it is a field configuration that is constant across 2 spatial directions and tends to a vacuum at positive infinity and to a distinct one at negative infinity across the third spatial direction -- it is a kink extended trivially to 3 dimensions. The point is that it is stated that the presence of a domain wall (which is just a way to refer to this exact field equations solution) causes the field to "choose" different vacuua at each side of the wall.

I don't understand this. What is meant by the sentence claimed above? Why and how the fact that there exists an exact field solution in which the field value is closer to a distinct vacuum in each side of the wall has a physical consequence? What is the difference between the classical and quantum cases?

I suppose this is related to the fact that these types of solutions should be the most important quantum corrections to a classical theory (at least this is the case for instantons), but I cannot convert this to a complete train of thought.

This is as much a qualitative as a technical question and I appreciate any insights.